# Magento2 - How to install and check coding standards of extension for Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I want to check **My Extension's** coding standard for **Magento Marketplace** before submitting it on **Magento Marketplace*. Can anyone tell me how can I install coding standard in `My Local Environment` and check my extension whether this extension is eligible or not for Magento Marketplace code standard.

Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento use [`EQP Coding Standard`](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp) tool for checking the coding standard of a module.https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp

Magento this tool used basically using [PHP_CodeSniffer tool](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).

If you want to in run `EQP Coding Standard` on your local system, then follow steps:

1. Go to your Magento root directory,  install this too using composer:

`composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/marketplace-eqp magento-coding-standard`

2. Then go to this tool directly using `cd magento-coding-standard`
3. run Composer update command `composer install` which will update module dependency packages.
   Also set config path *specific PHP version set paths to php binary dir*

`vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set php7.0_path /path/to/your/php7`

4. After that, you can use below  command for checkout code start of your module from **magento-coding-standard**  folder

   php vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2

use **MEQP2** for  magento2 extension.

Example:

> php vendor/bin/phpcs
>   /var/www/html/MagentoProkect/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule
>   --standard=MEQP2  --extensions=php,phtml

Here i give full path of my extension `/var/www/html/MagentoProkect/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule`

4.1. If you use windows and face some `path must be translated` related warning in command line then try below solution.
   Install `Cygwin` console from https://cygwin.com and then go to `magento-coding-standard` directory and run below command.

> vendor/bin/phpcs
>   F:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule
>   --standard=MEQP2 --severity=10 --extensions=php,phtml

5. After That, I have tun  ***code sniffer auto fixer command*** which is basic code standards issue.

> php vendor/bin/phpcbf /path/to/your/extension -extensions=php,phtml
>   --standard=MEQP2

**Example:**

> php vendor/bin/phpcbf /var/www/html/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule
>   --standard=MEQP2  --extensions=php,phtml

After re-run **Step 4** command for check out **the rest of error** which *you need to fix yourself manuall*y.

Comment: I will try and let you know, If My extension is pass in this than it will approved in Magento Marketplace ?

Comment: You have to follow also `https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Extension_Quality_Program_Overview.pdf` and

Comment: I got this error :  PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff' not found in vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard/EcgM2/Sniffs/Plugins/PluginSniff.php on line 7

Comment: run `composer install` command on `magento-coding-standard` folder

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nclrtq

Comment: Can you please help me to solve code_sniffer related issue.

Comment: `. Also set config path specific PHP version set paths to php binary dir

vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set php7.0_path /path/to/your/php7`

Comment: Currently I am solving config path related issue once I resolved it and all things working than I will accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: I am run command from "magento-coding-standard" folder  php vendor/bin/phpcs ../app/code/Cirkle/Behalf --standard=MEQP2
and got this error : http://prntscr.com/nd0yv5

Comment: Please make chat with me Some correction is required in your answer.

Comment: You can edit my answer.So you can edit  yourself

Comment: Ok I will  edit it.

Comment: Please remove php and run its work for me  

vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2

Answer (score 0):

Not just for Magento, the coding standard for any extensions or solutions before submissions follow the same. But in Magento, it is a stably even more conscious process.

Also, all must look for the best practices to pass the extension quality program curated by the Magento marketplace.

For adequate and proper flow, the Magento community follows several guidelines and verification tools to check if it stays the level to pass the Magento coding standards. It might go through - logical and practical coding structure, scalability, performance and absolute compatibility with the latest Magento version.

Technically, the code standard process for any Magento extension would have to count the following levels:

### Level 1:

The first level is a must one, and it checks all the extensions before letting them into the marketplace to examine the code structure and plagiarism issues.

### Level 2:

Extensions that pass Level 1 can enter level 2 with an official badge called “ Top Quality Badge” received from the platform. After all, the extension is free to go via a series of checks like - Documentation, Deep Code, Sanity Check/QA Review.

**Step 1** – Go to your Magento 2 root folder using the following command:

> $ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com
> Magento/marketplace-eqp Magento-coding-standard

**Step 2** – Set dynamic sniffs by running the following command:

> $ vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set m2-path /path/to/magento2

**Step 3** – Go to the Magento-coding-standard folder, which should be installed on your Magento root folder using the following command:

$ cd Magento-coding-standard

**Step 4** – Run your code against Magento 2 coding standards to check:

> $ vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP1 and $
> vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2

**Step 5** – Fixing Errors Automatically

PHP_CodeSniffer offers the PHP Code Beautifier and Fixer (phpcbf) tool. It can be used in phpcs to automatically generate and fix all fixable issues.

We highly recommend running the following command to fix as many sniff violations as possible:

> $ vendor/bin/phpcbf /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP1 and $
> vendor/bin/phpcbf /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2

If you are building an extension for Magento Marketplace, then make sure you run the following command on your version before submitting the extension for technical review:

$ vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2
--severity=10 --extensions=php,phtml

I hope it helps in submitting your Magento extension to the community marketplace.