# How Can I check Coding Standards Of my module for magento 2.4.4 and php 8.1?

Tags: magento2.4.4, magento-coding-standard

My extension have failed the coding standards of magento marketplace how can i check coding standards i have magento 2.4.4 installed and php 8.1.

Comment: get better idea from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270261/magento2-how-to-install-and-check-coding-standards-of-extension-for-magento-ma/270285#270285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should find what you need here: https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard

Answer (score 0):

you should follow `https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html`
explain by adobe devdoc.

Also get better idea from

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/270285/46039