# How to setup magento coding standard for the Magento 2 version

Tags: magento2, module, installation, directory, magento-coding-standard

I am trying to set the magento coding standard in the Magento 2 version. I followed this link: https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard.

When I check code sniffer for the directory path: **/public_html/magento-coding-standard/vendor/bin/phpcbf path to your extensions --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=php,phtml,xml,css,js**

It is shows me an issue of MEQP2 not insalled .

[image]

Can you please guide me how can installed the Magento coding standard for the MEQP2 ?

Comment: Check already provided answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270261/magento2-how-to-install-and-check-coding-standards-of-extension-for-magento-ma

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the EQP Coding Standard tool for checking the coding standard of a module.`https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp`

Magento a tool used basically using the PHP_CodeSniffer tool.

If you want to run EQP Coding Standard on your local system, then follow the steps:

Go to your Magento root directory, and install this too using composer:
`composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/marketplace-eqp` Magento-coding-standard

Then go to this tool directly using cd magento-coding-standard

run Composer update `command composer` install which will update module dependency packages. Also, set config path specific PHP version set paths to php binary dir

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set php7.0_path /path/to/your/php7
```

After that, you can use the below command for the checkout code start of your module from the Magento-coding-standard folder

```
php vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2
```

use MEQP2 for magento2 extension.

Example:

```
php vendor/bin/phpcs /var/www/html/MagentoProkect/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=php,phtml
```

Here I give the full path of my extension `/var/www/html/MagentoProkect/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule`

4.1. If you use windows and face some path that must be translated related warning in the command line then try the below solution. Install Cygwin console from https://cygwin.com and then go to the Magento-coding-standard directory and run the below command.

```
vendor/bin/phpcs F:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule --standard=MEQP2 --severity=10 --extensions=php,phtml
```

After That, I have run the code sniffer auto fixer command which is a basic code standards issue.

```
php vendor/bin/phpcbf /path/to/your/extension -extensions=php,phtml --standard=MEQP2
```

Example:

```
  php vendor/bin/phpcbf /var/www/html/app/code/DevAmitbera/CustomModule --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=php,phtml
```

After re-run
Step 4 command for checking out the rest of errors which you need to fix yourself manually.

Comment: I follow the same steps it is still not showing Magento 2 or MEQP2 option that will validate Magento 2 plugins.

Comment: Try this command make sure you update your vendor and module name--> 
 vendor/bin/phpcs --report=xml --report-file=MEQP.xml app/code/Vendor/ModuleName --standard=Magento2 --severity=10 -p